# Determine whether field is annotated with a given annotations

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I don't know if you managed to figure out what i am trying to do just from the title so I'll try to explain with example

Lets suppose I have created my own annotation `@VerifySomething`

And I have created test class for that annotation to make sure it works.

Now lets suppose that I have class `SomeClass` with field `something` anoted with annotation `@VerifySomething`

```
class SomeClass {
    @VerifySomething
    String something;
}
```

So far so good, but now I want to create `test class` for my `SomeClass` however I don't see any point in verifying all the test cases of something as I have already checked that `@VerifySomething` works as it should in class which tests that annotation, however I need to make sure that field something actually has `@VerifySomething` annotation without copy pasting all these test cases.

So my question is, is there a way to check if some field has one or more required annotation without writing test cases I have already written in annotation test class to make sure it works as it should.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `getAnnotation` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class))) to determine if there is a specific Annotation on the field, which takes the annotation class as a parameter:

```
field.getAnnotation( SomeAnnotation.class );
```

Here is a method you can use to verify that a class has a field annotated by given annotation:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

public class TestHasAnnotatedField {
    @Test
    public void testHasFieldsWithAnnotation() throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Class<?>[] classesToVerify = new Class[] {MyClass1.class, MyClass2.class};
        for (Class<?> clazz : classesToVerify) {
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("something");
            Assert.notNull(field.getAnnotation(NotNull.class));
        }
    }
    static class MyClass1 { @NotNull String something; }
    static class MyClass2 { @NotNull String something; }
}
```

Comment: Just adding to this excellent answer to say that if you define your own annotation and would like to be able to check it programmatically (via `field.getAnnotation`) you'll need to annotate your annotation declaration with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.

Comment: Or `Field#isAnnotationPresent` with boolean result.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I am following, but in case you want to verify whether a class and or its properties have a given Bean Validation constraint, you can use the meta data api. The entry point is *Validator#getConstraintsForClass(SomeClass.class)*. You get a *BeanDescriptor*. From there you can do _beanDescriptor#getConstraintsForProperty("something") which gives you a *PropertyDescriptor*. Via *propertyDescriptor#getConstraintDescriptors()* you get then a set of *ConstraintDescriptors* which you can iterate to verify that a given constraint annotation was used.

Note, this is a Bean Validation specific solution compared to generic reflection as in the answer above, but it depends what you are really after. To be honest I don't quite understand your use case yet.